# Will I be banned for using mods or skins?

Tags: team-fortress-2, mods

I downloaded TF2 yesterday. I am liking this game. I found out that there are mods and skins available online. I also found tutorials to use these. But I am not sure if I would get banned for using them. May someone please tell me?

Comment: Aim-bots, for example, and other methods to cheat are more likely to get you in trouble in certain situations, but generally speaking, no. Skins are definitely fine. As for mods, that may depend on what you mean. Your question would be able to be answered more clearly if you could be a bit more specific about your setup and provide an example? Which mods are you using here? Are you talking about hosting your own server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom skins are client side and do not interact with VAC. This means you cannot be banned for using them. It is possible, however, for servers to disable them by changing certain settings.

"Mods" covers a wide range of things from perfectly legal scripts to completely illegal aim-bots and hacks. Without knowing the exact mod you're talking about, I can't say whether it'd be allowed, potentially disabled or illegal.

Comment: Thanks @studoku , can I post the links of mods here?

Comment: @RakeshJuyal I'd advise against it.  Asking if a list of mods is 'legal' would be troubling to answer at best, and may depend on the server.  You'd probably do better making an inquiry on a TF2 forum.  In general though, scripted actions are usually considered okay.  Auto-aiming scripts are frowned upon.  Other mods would vary from server to server, but the less intrusive into the gameplay they are, the more likely they'd be allowable.

Answer (score 1):

Using anything available under `SteamWorkshop` is perfectly safe, also custom skins do not interfere with VAC, anthing else might trigger a VAC ban and it's not worth risking for. Unless you want to play on a server that is not VAC secured but there chances are you will run into cheaters.

Answer (score 0):

Skins and mods do not trigger the VAC unless you modify core files such as DLL, however, this is done on your own risk. Some trollers can mask their skins as actual hacks just to watch the world burn (get you banned).

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what the people said above, you can look for servers that aren't VAC-secured if you're worried about being able to play with mods installed.